# mysql Invalid column count in CSV input while importing csv file

Tags: mysql, sql, csv

I have a table in the database called `locations` which contains 2 columns(`id` which is auto incremented , `location`) , And I have a csv contains 1 column looks like :
[image]

When I try to import that file to `locations` table , I get this error `invalid column count in CSV input on line 1`.

Also I tried `CSV using LOAD DATA` but I get this : `MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows)`

Comment: [How to LOAD DATA INFILE in mysql with first col being Auto Increment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6017032/how-to-load-data-infile-in-mysql-with-first-col-being-auto-increment#6018145)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use:

```
$array = array_map('str_getcsv', file('file.csv'));
```

You have more option to check variables.

Answer (score 0):

If Java is supported in your machine, Use below solution

https://dbisweb.wordpress.com/

The simple configuration required to do is

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
> <config>
>   <connections>
>       <jdbc name="mysql">
>           <driver>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver>
>           <url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test1</url>
>           <user>root</user>
>           <password></password>
>       </jdbc>
>   </connections>
>   <component-flow>
>       <execute name="file2table" enabled="true">
>           <migrate>
>               <source>
>                   <file delimiter="," header="false" path="D:/test_source.csv"/>
>               </source>
>               <destination>
>                   <table connection="mysql">locations</table>
>               </destination>
>               <mapping>
>                   <column source="1" destination="location" />
>               </mapping>
>           </migrate>
>       </execute>
>   </component-flow>
> </config>
> ```

If you are interested, Same can be achieved by Java code.

> 

```
Source source = new File("D:/test_source.csv", ',', false);
        Destination destination = new Table("locations", new JDBCConnection("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver", "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test1", "root", ""));
        List<Mapping> mapping = new ArrayList<>();
        mapping.add(new Mapping("1", "location", null));
        Component component = new MigrateExecutor(source, destination, mapping);
        component.execute();
```